# Primefaces: RequestContext.execute - Javascript called twice

Tags: javascript, primefaces, requestcontext

I'm using primefaces and have a problem executing JavaScript at the end of an ajax call. I add some action to the RequestContext, and it is executed twice!

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert('I'm here!')");
```

It is also embedded twice in the XML which I get back from the server - two times the same component and same  node.

Primefaces Version is 5.3.10

Any ideas what is going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: endDocument in PrimePartialResponseWriter is also called twice. It contains a call to encodeScripts which returns the <eval> nodes...

Comment: [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: OK, it seems that it was a deployment-problem. We deployed it again and the problem is solved...

Comment: Then please either remove the question or create this as an answer

Comment: I have the same problem when calling the execute method from a p:commandButton. It doesn't happen when calling it in the @PostConstruct method.

Comment: I have exactly same problem but after redeploy also problem not solved

Answer (score -4, accepted):

OK, it seems that it was a deployment-problem. We deployed it again and the problem is solved...

Answer (score 4):

It has been a while since last answer and problem seems to be solved but I believe I know what is going on and the reason new deployment solved the problem.

It seems it happens when you have more than one primefaces*.jar inside EAR (i.e. EAR/lib and WAR/WEB-INF/lib.

If anyone else is facing this problem, try to remove from EAR/lib (or EAR root), keep only one primefaces*.jar in EAR.

Answer (score 0):

I avoided such error by changing version of Primefaces from 6.0 to 6.1 in POM. (6.1 version was in libs of server Payara)

Comment: So effectively you also made sure there is just one PrimeFaces version? But which is used?